# Opening QML file in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, qml

I have been trying to open a map which I downloaded from the ESA website.

There are several files in the folder including .cpd, .csv, .dsr, .qml, .tif and so on. I was trying to open the .tif image in ArcGIS Desktop but it would not display anything. Then I was just trying to identify but I realized something was not right here. Apparently .qml files could be opened in QGIS, but I have no idea how to work around QGIS.

Is it possible to open the QML file in ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Can you share in your post screenshot of raster layer properties (Style tab) from QGIS or link to ESA data for download. Both will be helpful.

Comment: Qml file is used for storing the rendering styles of a layer in QGIS. ArcGIS does not understand it at all but you should be able to open the tiff file with ArcGIS. You write that ArcGIS does not display anything and my guess is that you have downloaded some measurement data that contains only very low values in pixels and therefore you must apply histogram stretch for making the image visible for bare eyes.

Comment: Was any solution ever found for this? I would like to use QML files to store and retrieve symbology for ArcGIS desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any way to open a QML file in ArcGIS Desktop for reading or conversion.

If you wish for ArcGIS Desktop to be enhanced so that it can then you could [post an ArcGIS Idea](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas/).